# WiFi direct Ip address

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

Do the Wifi-Direct Ip_address and Ip address given by any WIFI router to the smart-phone same?
I am below code to get my IP address.

```
public String getP2PIpAddr() {
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

   String ipString = String.format(
   "%d.%d.%d.%d",
   (ip & 0xff),
   (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

   return ipString;
}
```

but its giving me 0.0.0.0 when i am not connected to any wifi router.But it is returning me IP address given by router to phone but not the wifi-direct IPAddress..

Please Help...

Thanks In advance..

Answer (score 1):

No the IP addresses are not the same.
You are making mistakes here, `getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE)` returns [WifiP2pManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html) not `WifiManager`.

Secondly
You use `wifiManager.getConnectionInfo()` when you are connected to a normal Wifi network i.e. via a router or hotspot. You do not get IP when connected via WifiDirect like this as it is not a normal wifi network. Thus, the reason you are getting IP as `0.0.0.0`.

Now the main the question what are the IPs in WifiDirect.
If you are a GroupOwner you have fixed GO_IP = `192.168.43.1`. So, in [onConnectionInfoAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener.html) or [onGroupInfoAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener.html), you can do `info.isGroupOwner()` and if you are not the groupOwner then the other system is, hence his IP is **GO_IP**, then this system can communicate to the **GO** using **GO_IP**

Now if GO wants to communicate with client, he can get his IP using `NetworkInterfaces`. Refer this [how to get the client IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126598/1978379).

I think this all should solve your problem.